# How to add margin for Twitter's Bootstrap help-block?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When `help-block` style is used at the end of `fieldset`, then it looks well, but when used at the top, looks like there is no enough margin at the bottom - please see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/YgUPt/).

I've tried to use the following CSS:

```
.help-block .top {
  margin-bottom: 5px;    
}
```

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set a margin-bottom on the `.top` element within `.help-block`

That means it is looking for a structure similar to the following:

```
<div class="help-block">
  <div class="top">
  </div>
</div>
```

You need to apply the style to the actual element.  Either `.top` `.help-block` or give it its own id.

You can also specifically add a property only to the first `.help-block` by using an nth-child selector.  However this is not supported in IE8 or below.

http://jsfiddle.net/YgUPt/1/

Comment: Thanks, got it now. Here is the approach I've chosen - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/YgUPt/2/